# How to speed up word2vec similarity calculation?

Tags: tensorflow, gensim

I trained a Word2Vec model using Gensim, and I have two sets of words:

```
S1 = {'','','' ...}
S2 = {'','','' ...}
```

for each word w1 in S1, I want to find top 5 words that are most similar to w1. I am currently doing this way:

```
model = w2v_model
 word_similarities = {}
 for w1 in S1:
    similarities = {}
    for w2 in S2:
       if w1 in model.wv and w2 in model.wv:
           similarity = model.similarity(w1, w2)
           similarities[w2] = similarity
    word_similarties[w1] = similarities
```

Then for each word in word_similarities, I can get the top N from its dict values. If S1 and S2 are large, this becomes very slow.

Is there a quicker way to compute large pairs of words in Word2Vec, either in genism or tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the relative sizes of your model, `S1`, & `S2`, you may want to use the `most_similar()` method of gensim's various word-vector classes – which will use a bulk, optimized vector-comparison operations to check against **all** vectors in your model – then filter down to just the results in `S2`.

Alternatively, if `S2` is much smaller than the full size of `model.wv`, and especially if you'll be re-using the same `S2` set of word-vector many times, you could consider creating your own `KeyedVectors` instance with **just** the `S2` words in it, by 1st creating an empty `KeyedVectors` then adding all the `S2` words to it, then using `s2.most_similar(positive=[target_word_vector], topn=5)`.

Comment: could you write a solution based on your 2nd suggestion?

Comment: See the `KeyedVectors.add()` method: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.add